# Close all windows of the same application in gnome shell

Tags: gnome

As the title says, Is there a shortcut to close all windows of the same application in gnome shell, or an extension to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wanna test-ride the [**window-options-gnome-shell-extension**](https://bitbucket.org/mathematicalcoffee/window-options-gnome-shell-extension) from bitbucket.org, last updated Nov. 2012 (thus appears to be actively maintained).

> ... added option to close the current window (as opposed to the '**Quit**'
>   button that **closes** the entire **application** (i.e. **all** its **windows**)).

Enjoy!

ps:

Alternatively, you may (also) want to look into this [SOLVED thread](http://forums.worldofgnome.org/discussion/50/solveddash-to-dock-how-to-quit-an-app-without-activating-it-and-quitting/p1), which seems to offer yet another solution.

---

**EDIT:**
"[Quit from dash](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/559/quit-from-dash/)" is now an extension on the gnome extensions website.

Comment: This is quite useful, but I use a task bar extension that hides the original window title bar, thus I cannot use it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you check *both* options?

Comment: The extension link in the second option redirects me to a broken link; ("The file you are looking for has been deleted or moved.").

Comment: I found the extension in the second link in the gnome extensions website. Here's the link
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/559/quit-from-dash/

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following command in terminal.

```
killall <application>
```

or press super key (windows/apple/ubuntu key) and type xkill. And click on the application you want to kill.

Comment: A good tool, but it would be a lot nicer if there was something like the 'Quit' option in Unity's context menu

Comment: Do you mean like a shortcut? yeah than you will need to program a script i think :/. If you wan't to see all the commands available on unity just hold super ;).

Comment: For example `killall evince` closes all open pdf windows.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using UNITY and its LAUNCHER, you can do so ("Close all windows of the same application") by selecting the target application in LAUNCHER and then using the `right arrow` button to "Quit".

Comment: The question and title specifically mentions GNOME shell.

Comment: I know. I'm trying to be helpful rather than punctilious; the question asks for a shortcut, and the method I described is very short-cut for me in my set-up. But attaching a shortcut to a command as in Thomas Vanmellaerts answer is fine, too, of course! That's a matter of taste. Further, I'd generally prefer to gently end-close my applications than brutally kill ("execute") 'em.

Comment: @iBelieve Could be there is no option in GNOME Shell to close .. like in Launcher, at least not by default: https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet

Comment: See an alternative approach in my 2nd answer, specifically aimed at the [GNOME Shell (as opposed to Unity](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-reasons-gnome-shell-ubuntus-unity-opinion/))...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which will close all windows of a certain application when you click on one of its windows (using `killall`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys,os, subprocess

# Function based on code from Apport
def get_window_pid():
    xprop = subprocess.Popen(['xprop', '_NET_WM_PID'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (out, err) = xprop.communicate()
    if xprop.returncode == 0:
        try:
            return int(out.split()[-1])
        except ValueError:
            error_message(_('Cannot identify package'),
                    _('xprop failed to determine process ID of the window') + '\n\n' + err)
            return -1
    else:
        error_message(_('Cannot identify package'),
                _('xprop failed to determine process ID of the window') + '\n\n' + err)
        return -1

def get_window_exe():
    pid = get_window_pid()

    if pid == -1:
        return ''

    return os.path.realpath('/proc/' + str(pid) + '/exe')

def close_all():
    app = get_window_exe()
    os.system('killall ' + app)

if __name__=='__main__':
    close_all()
```

Save this to a file (such as `closeall`), and make sure it is in the system path and is executable.

Then you can run it at any time by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `closeall`.

Comment: Does xkill not actually the same?

Comment: Wow, nice effort. This is like `xkill` suggested by 
Thomas Vanmellaerts. But I am looking for something like the 'Quit' option in unity launcher, thanks for your help.

Comment: @ThomasVanmellaerts This closes all the windows of a particular application (not just one). I don't think `xkill` can do that, though I'm not sure what the `-all` option does.